# Unable to show icon when i hover using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to the framework. My objective is to show the icon when i hover on the tab, But i couldn't able to perform hover. 
I've tried by giving css as `display: none` and hover too, but didn't worked.
Can anyone help me in solving this issue?

Here is the code:

```
  showIcon: {
    // display: "none",
    "&.hover": {
      display: "visible"
    }
  }
 <Card>
        <CardHeader
          className={classes.header}
          avatar={<Avatar aria-label="recipe">R</Avatar>}
          action={
            <div>
              <IconButton
                className={classes.showIcon}
                aria-label="settings"
                aria-controls="simple-menu"
                onClick={this.handleClick}
              >
                <MoreVertIcon />
              </IconButton>
              <Menu id="simple-menu" keepMounted anchorEl={this.state.menu}>
                <MenuItem>Profile</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem>change password</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem>Logout</MenuItem>
              </Menu>
            </div>
          }
          title="Shrimp and Chorizo Paella"
          subheader="September 14, 2016"
        />
      </Card>
```

[Here is the sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-galois-ykshu)

Comment: your css `display: visible` is not valid css. Its `display: block`. The `visible` value only exists for the `visibility` property

Comment: @japrescott - Nope, Still it is not working!

Comment: please have a look at my answer and the working example

Comment: @japrescott - Hi, If i dont have any hover for Card Header then how do we make it work?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. If you dont want to use css to show/hide the icon or if your react-component needs to know when someone is hovering, look at @Val Berthe answer

Comment: @japrescott - Could you please preview my code. I've updated it. I mean that, if i don't want hover for card header then how can we hide the icon? I apologize for not explaining properly

Comment: have you looked at [my solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-snow-wmlz7?file=/src/Sample.jsx)? I dont understand what you are trying to do. If you want to hide the icon, you can remove it from the react-component or you can use set it to `display:none`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forked your code and [fixed it for you](https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-snow-wmlz7?file=/src/Sample.jsx);
What was wrong? All css pseudo classes need to have a `:` delimiter, not a `.`. Additionally, the hover was on the wrong element